# Python: Enumeration

Tags: python, enumerate

People have said that the enumerate function is a hidden trick in python. I am still unsure as to what it does. The documentation just tells me that it returns an enumerate object. That doesn't exactly help me in understanding this concept.

What does enumeration do?

Comment: The documentation includes examples and a sample Python implementation of what `enumerate()` does. What exactly about the examples is unclear?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it talks about it using lists. Can it be used in dictionaries?

Comment: I can for example understand that the term `iterator` isn't immediately clear and what the `__next__()` method on an iterator does. But both concepts link to further documentation as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think i sort of understand the first bit of code they have in the 3.4 docs

Comment: Dictionaries can be iterated over, yielding keys. `enumerate()` can be used on any iterable, including other `enumerate()` results.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how would you set it up for a dictionary?? like if you have a list, how can you enumerate it to have an assigned key to it? Or is that not the function?

Comment: I think that you need to follow that link about iterators; you can also [look at the iterators section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) of the Python tutorial.

Comment: I think that makes a little more sense now. @MartijnPieters

Comment: The enumerate docstring, part of interactive `help(enumerate)` output, says "Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument. enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list  (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enumerate()` can be used with any iterable. It enumerates the values returned by the iterable.

```
3>> enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'])
<enumerate object at 0x7f1340c44a50>
3>> list(enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
3>> list(enumerate({'a', 'b', 'c'}))
[(0, 'c'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a')]
3>> list(enumerate({'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0}))
[(0, 'c'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a')]
```

Note that the `set` and `dict` results are *not* in error; they are arbitrarily ordered, hence do not necessarily "come out" the same way they "go in". And as always, iterating over a mapping yields its keys.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate pairs the index of each element with the element:

```
for i in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']):
    print I

(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(2, 'c')
```

In addition, you can create your own enumeration by yourself:

```
enum = lambda l: zip([i for i in range(len(l))], l)
```

Comment: Yes an enumerate object is simply a generator which can be used to build an iterator. Basically, you can loop through this object as if it were a list, but in reality it's not.

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate()` is a fancy tool that gives you the index of the item in the iterable as well as the item. There is nothing you can't do with you standard for loop.

lets say we have this simple list. `lst = ['red', 'car', 'machine', 'go', 'cloud', 'cabbages']`

An example of `enumerate()`

```
for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    print(str(item) + " Is item number: " + str(index))
```

without `enumerate()` this could might look like.

```
for count in range(len(lst)):
    print(str(lst[count]) + " Is item number: " + str(count))
```

Both produce the same output.

```
>>> red Is item number: 0
>>> car Is item number: 1
>>> machine Is item number: 2
>>> go Is item number: 3
>>> cloud Is item number: 4
>>> cabbages Is item number: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

When iterating (`for`) enumerate object it returns position and thing which would usually be returned:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
for pos, x in enumerate(a):
    print(pos, x)
```

Example above should be used instead of:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
for x in range(len(a)):
    print(x, a[x])
```

because of code clarity.